# Active state using Javascript on Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to use Javascript so that when the page loads by default, it has the first tab colored dark green. Also, once you click the tabs the active state changes to dark green. I have it set up in the CSS so that the hover state changes to dark green, but I need an active state using JavaScript.

Thank you so much for the help! I stripped a lot of code out of this.

```css
.tabs_accordion {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}


.tabs_accordion > input {
  /*position: relative;
  left: -50000px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0;*/
  display: none;
}

.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ ul.tabs > li:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ div.content > label:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(1):checked ~ div.content > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  border-top: none;
  background-image:url(picture-1.jpg);
  min-height: 380px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ ul.tabs > li:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ div.content > label:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(2):checked ~ div.content > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  border-top: none;
  background-image:url(picture-2.jpg);
  min-height: 380px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ ul.tabs > li:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ div.content > label:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tabs_accordion > input:nth-child(3):checked ~ div.content > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  border-top: none;
  background-image:url(picture-3.jpg);
  min-height: 380px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
}



.tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: #deeab4;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color:#333333;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li {
  display: table-cell;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 238px;
  
}

.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
   background-color: #8cd600;
 
}


/* begin controls hover */
.tabs_accordion [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  background: green;
}
/* end controls hover */

.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label {
  display: block;
  height: 74px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px solid #c8c8c8;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:focus {
  background-color: #8cd600;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li label:active {
  background-color: #8cd600;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #8cd600;
   color:#FFFFFF;
}

.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:hover + li > label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.tabs_accordion ul.tabs li:first-child label {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > label {
  display: block;
  background-color: #deeab4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align:center;
}
.tabs_accordion div.content > div {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px; 

  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

  .tabs_accordion ul.tabs {
    display: table;
  }
  .tabs_accordion div.content > label {
    display: none;
  }
  .tabs_accordion div.content > div {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tabs_accordion">

<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_2" id="tab_2_content_control" tabindex="0" />
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_1" id="tab_1_content_control" checked="checked" tabindex="0" />
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="tab_3" id="tab_3_content_control" tabindex="0" /> 
  
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label></li>
    <li><label for="tab_2_content_control">Option 2</label></li>
    <li><label for="tab_3_content_control">Option 3</label></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="content">
    
    <label for="tab_1_content_control">Option 1</label>
    <div class="tab_1_content">
      
    </div>
      
    <label for="tab_2_content_control">Option 2</label>
    <div class="tab_2_content">
    </div>  
    
    <label for="tab_3_content_control">Option 3</label>
    <div class="tab_3_content">
    </div>    
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new css class for active tab

```
.activeTab
{  
   background-color: green;
}
```

And in your document ready event, you can get the first tab item(li element) and then add this new css class to that. Also when user clicks, remove the current active class and set the `activeTab` class to the newly clicked item.

```
$(function(){  

  //Make first one active
  $(".tabs>li").first().addClass("activeTab");

  $(".tabs>li").click(function(e){

    var _this = $(this); 

    //Remove existing active one  
    $(".activeTab").removeClass("activeTab");   

   //Set the css class to the clicked one
     _this.addClass("activeTab");

  });


})
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tuzixiresu/edit?html,css,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: You just saved my life. This worked perfectly. If I could give you plus 100 rep I would. Thank you so very much!